# How to convert WKB to radians or utm in postgresql?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, well-known-binary

I am using PostgreSQL with postgis, the geometries are in UTM and stored as WKB with several shapes types (point, polygon, linestring...). Is there a way to convert the WKB to a list of points in radians or utm without the string parsing of the shape type and each point?

Thanks.

Comment: WKB is a data format. Radians are and angular measurement unit. UTM is a map projection coordinate system. I suggest you read nicklas and nickves answers and try to clarify what you really wish to do.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your table is called mTable. And you geometry column is called geom, and that it contains a mix of geometry types (points, linestrings, polygonts and etc)

For points you can use the following:

```
select 
     gid,st_x(geom) as X, st_y(geom_ as) as Y, from mTable 
where 
     GeometryType(geom) = 'POINT' OR GeometryType(geom) = 'MULTIPOINT';
```

For polygons I assume you want the **centroid** of it.

```
select 
     gid,st_x(st_centroid((geom)) as X, st_y(st_centroid((geom_ as) as Y, from mTable 
where 
     GeometryType(geom) = 'POLYGON' OR GeometryType(geom) = 'MULTIPOLYGON';
```

The same principle applies for the other geometry types.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clearify. Your geometries is not stored as wkb. It is stored in PostGIS internal format. But that makes no differens.

The point is that how You present your geometries is all up to You. If You just ask for the geometri You will Get it as wkb because that is the default output for the geometry type. If You use st_astext You will Get it in the wkb-format as You describe in your question.

To Get just list of coordinates You can use st_dumppoints to Explode all vertexpoints an use st_x and st_y as described by nickves to Get the coordinates.